# Angular 6 *ngIf animation sequencing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two elements in my component that use the same fade animation. Only one is on screen at a time, they both have *ngIf directives to control their visibility. It's a simple fade in/fade out animation.

When my component state changes a certain way, the *ngIf conditions change and one element is removed and the other is added. Here is my animation:

```
  animations: [
    trigger('fade', [
      state('in', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'rotateX(0deg)' })),
      transition(':enter', [style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'rotateX(90deg)' }), animate('0.2s')]),
      transition(':leave', [style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'rotateX(0deg)' }), animate('0.2s')])
    ])
  ]
```

And here are my two elements in my component template:

```
<div @fade *ngIf="isErrorState" id="error-message" class="status-message">
          <div class="message">Oops! We encountered an error while processing your signup. Please try again.</div>
        </div>
        <div @fade *ngIf="isLoadingState" id="loading-message" class="status-message">
          <div class="spinner-container">
            <app-spinner></app-spinner>
          </div>
          <div class="message">We're processing your signup, hang on...</div>
        </div>
```

The animation works, but the problem is they are both animating at the same time, so they are both shown on screen together. Is there a way to sequence the animations so one doesn't start to fade in until the other is done fading out?

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides a `stagger()` function for this [API](https://angular.io/api/animations/stagger). I'd have to play around with the animation object to get it working for your example, the they offer the following:

```
trigger('listAnimation', [
  transition('* => *', [ // each time the binding value changes
    query(':leave', [
      stagger(100, [
        animate('0.5s', style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
    ]),
    query(':enter', [
      style({ opacity: 0 }),
      stagger(100, [
        animate('0.5s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ])
    ])
  ])
])
```

Spin up a stackblitz with your example and I can possibly help piece it together.